# For Loops output not what i wanted

Tags: java

I am a newbie in java and doing practiceit questions online.I came across this question and was stuck for quite some time.

Write a class named diceSum that prompts the user for a desired sum, then repeatedly rolls two six-sided dice until their sum is the desired sum. Here is the expected dialogue with the user:

```
Desired dice sum: 9
4 and 3 = 7
3 and 5 = 8
5 and 6 = 11
5 and 6 = 11
1 and 5 = 6
6 and 3 = 9
```

This is what i have done.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class diceSum{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.print("Desired dice sum: ");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int input=sc.nextInt();

        Random rnd=new Random();
        int r1=rnd.nextInt(7);
        int r2=rnd.nextInt(7);

        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
             sum=r1+r2;
            System.out.println(r1 + "and" + r2 + "=" + sum);

        }

    }
}
```

My output is

```
Desired dice sum:9
0 and 2=2
0 and 2=2
0 and 2=2
0 and 2=2
0 and 2=2
0 and 2=2
```

I dont understand how come it will print 0 and 2 for 6 times without giving another Random number.I am thinking if i should create a few more int r3=rnd.nextInt(7),int r4=rnd.nextInt(7).
But i was thinking it will be lengthy but it is a possible way to do it.

Comment: You need to actually get more random ints in your loop there...

Comment: Because you create the random numbers outside the loop.

Comment: So i should create more int r3,int r4 and so on?

Comment: Step through the code with debugger, and it should become clear why you don't get new random numbers. If you do not see it right away from that code, you *really* should step through it, it should be enlightening!

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
int r1;
int r2;
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
     r1=rnd.nextInt(6) + 1;
     r2=rnd.nextInt(6) + 1;
     sum=r1+r2;
     System.out.println(r1 + "and" + r2 + "=" + sum);
     if (sum == input){
         // This will break once you get the value.
         break;
     }
}
```

To continue and get new random numbers.
Also use `rnd.nextInt(6) + 1` to get 1 - 6 (without 0).

You assignment is to continue the checking till you find, and not only 6 times. Yo should use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: Sorry just to clarify.If i put r1 and r2 into the loop,they will keep looping and give me new outputs right?Because i always get my output wrong as i dont know when should i put those variables?Inside or outside the loops?

Comment: You should declare the variables outside the loop but assign them inside.

Comment: Sorry,just to clarify again.So i will initalize int r1=0 and r2=0 outside the loop and do r1=rnd.nextInt(6) + 1; and   r2=rnd.nextInt(6) + 1; inside the loop

Comment: You dont need to set it to zero, but you can. My code should work...

Comment: Hi.Really sorry for asking so many questions.isnt this "if (sum == input){ break;  redundant?

Comment: No. If the second chance got the value, it'll not get to third check, but "break" the loop and continue the rest of the code. But you should use "while" loop instead. I think you should read more about JAVA before asking others to solve your problems...

Answer (score 1):

```
int r1;
int r2;
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
     r1=rnd.nextInt(6) + 1;
     r2=rnd.nextInt(6) + 1;
     sum=r1+r2;
     System.out.println(r1 + "and" + r2 + "=" + sum);
     if (sum == input){
         break;
     }
}
```

but here also you are not sure to get  same numbers like

```
4 and 3 = 7
3 and 5 = 8
5 and 6 = 11
5 and 6 = 11
1 and 5 = 6    
6 and 3 = 9
```

Comment: How about indenting the code properly and showing what to do explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the declaration/initialization of `r1` and `r2` into the loop. Otherwise, they are set once, and remain in place through the rest of the program run.

Note that the assignment does not ask you to do six throws, it asks you to do as many as you need to get to the desired sum. In order to ensure that the loop *can* stop, you should check that the entered number is at least two and at most twelve.

In addition, this is wrong:

```
int r2=rnd.nextInt(7);
```

it gives you a number from 0 to 6, inclusive, but a real dice throw cannot produce a zero. Instead, you need to write

```
int r2=rnd.nextInt(6)+1;
```

Your loop should look like this:

```
int sum;
do {
    int r1=rnd.nextInt(6) + 1;
    int r2=rnd.nextInt(6) + 1;
    sum=r1+r2;
    System.out.println(r1 + "and" + r2 + "=" + sum);
} while (sum != input);
```